# Signal handling in Linux (CentOS) C

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, signals

I am fairly new to operating systems and am most comfortable in C++, however I am trying to fill in my knowledge gaps and get used to C syntax.

I keep coming across some syntax which I don't know how to interpret, it is of the following form:

void (*sa_sigaction) (int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *ctx)

There are 3 things that are confusing me:

1. Is sa_sigaction a pointer? I assume it is the function name. Can it also be a pointer?
2. Why is sa_sigaction in brackets? Does this have any syntactical relevance?
3. is 'void ctx' a void pointer? (which is what it looks like to me, but I don't understand why a void pointer would be a paramter).

I really hope that I am not asking a silly question - If I am please point me in the right direction to some reading material, I don't know which subject I would need to start reading up on in the C language.

An answer to whether my 3 interpretations of the synatx are correct would be greatly appreciated :)

Many thanks & happy coding

Comment: search for `function pointers`,for example http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for the prompt response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Yes, it's both a pointer and a function.

2) Yes, that's the syntax for declaring a function pointer.

3) Yes, that's a void pointer. They're very useful for passing memory addresses without a type.

Like was suggested by @user2485710 check out [this tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html) on function pointers.

Comment: It all looks so simple now! Thanks!

Comment: @user3438496 I like function pointers especially for when I have to make a decision on which function I want to call, but they all have the exact same parameters. I can make an array of pointers, and then call the array with the proper index element to call the right function. For example, if you were to make a calculator...you might pass two ints to add, sub, mult, and div, so you could make a small array of functions and use the operator to decide which to call.